# Can I use MemoryCach in place of Session?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I have a aspx page that is hitting the database over and over. Given that the data does not change often, I wanted at least store the data in a session object. I just learn that session object for our application are stored in the database.

After researching, I've found a class called **MemoryCache**, which cache data in memory. I'd like to know whether I can use that class to store data just the time some one his working on that page and then destroy it at the end of the operation?

Can someone explain if I can use **MemoryCache** for that purpose.

Thank for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use it to cache data between page loads. The MemoryCache object is the replacement for the ASP.NET only Cache object. It's values can be persisted for as long as the CLR process is alive i.e. as long as the server doesn't go down.

Comment: What if something goes wrong or the user just closes the browser's window, will the data stays in the memory indefinitely? Also, in the case things go well, can I remove the data from the memory?

Comment: The data will stay in the cache object until the server is restarted, or until the expiry period of the cached item is hit, whichever comes first. Having said that, you have to keep in mind that the cache object is **per process**, so all cached items will be accessible by all sessions.

Comment: Those data serve to populate dropdownlists, so nothing fancy. However, is there  a way to setup the expiration date? That way I can make it shorter. Otherwise, if there is no way to setup the expiration date, how long it will take the object to expire? In fact, I looked at the MSDN page, and I don't see something that will  serve that purpose.